# Load a XML into Database using SSIS 2012

Tags: ssis

I have a XML-File which is stored on a server. It can be reached over a URL. I need to Load the XML-Data into my Database, using SSIS 2012/Visual Studio 2010.

I've done this before in SSIS 2008 and it worked like a charm. Now I moved to 2012 and I am getting the following Error: "[XML-Source [46]] Error: The file "http://www.xxxx.xml" was not found. Please verify the file path and try again."

Anyone knows?

Comment: That URL looks bad. Do you mean a local network server like `http://servername/xxxx.xml`, or an internet address like `http://www.somewhere.com/xxxx.xml`. (You should also explain that "XML-Quelle" just means "XML-Source", for anyone who doesn't know how to read that.)

Comment: The url is correct. It's not the problem Iam facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix for VS 2010 and VS 2012.

FIX: SSIS 2012 XML Source task cannot load data from a URI
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2991526

Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close the xml file before loading. you have to generate an XSD file make sure the schema defination is correct in the XSD file.

Comment: Schema is correct, since it worked before. I can't close it, because it isn't stored on my pc.